# Gift card activity table (logging)

Tags: mysql

I have a simple gift card table:

```
- id (auto incrementing integer)
- gift_card_number (varchar; unique)
- value (decimal)
```

I want to create a logging table to track updates to the gift card. A gift card can be updated manually or through a sale

I am thinking for the log table:

```
- id (auto incrementing integer)
- date (Timestamp)
- giftcard_id (foreign key reference)
- type (SALE, UPDATE)
- old_amount (Decimal)
- new_amount (Decimal) 
- log_message (TEXT)
- employee_id (person who did updating; foreign key)
```

Do you think this will meet requirements? Is there a better way to organize this data?

Comment: what does gift_card_table.value represent (don't say value :>)

Comment: I wouldn't store old amount/new amount, I'd just store the transaction amount, and use a trigger to update the balance in the card table itself.

Comment: In addition to what pierce said, value is a reserved word, so try not to use it. Same with date, since date is also a type it's a good idea to use another name.

Comment: value is the balance of the gift card

Comment: i would go with just one decimal in log/transaction_table, let it switch hit as a positive, negative (but that is just me). as such you could lose the type column

Comment: @McAdam331, Barmar shamed me yesterday on that one with a timestamp. the following is legal: create table timestamp
( a int not null,
 value decimal(12,4) not null
);

Comment: @DrewPierce legal, yes. But do you find that readable?

Comment: no, but i did go crawl under my rock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are logging pretty much all information that could be logged about the updates, so it'll probably meet your requirements.

You could remove the "old_amount" and "new_amount" and just make your "log_message" more verbose (unless you are planning to filter log entries based on the values). A more generic table structure could then be replicated for logging other tables as well, and could be presented using a common interface in your application.

Removing those fields could be particularly useful if you then add more fields to the table and don't want your log table to have so many columns for storing all the old/new values.

You might want to remove the foreign key reference from the log table so that you can later on be able to actually remove gift cards without deleting the log information associated with it (you could also log the gift card deletions using the same table).

Same goes for the "employee_id", you don't specify if it's a foreign key or not. I'd avoid making it a foreign key to be able to keep logs for removed users.